# Find files older than X and Count them

Tags: linux, scripting

Using Linux.  What I need to do is determine the number of files in a directory(recursively) that are older than DATE and echo that number.

I have:
find /u1/database/prod/arch -type f -mtime +10  -exec ls -laR | wc -l \;

That lists the files fine.

And then I have:
ls -laR | wc -l

Which lets me count the files recursively.

But I can't seem to put them together.  I think I need a script to do this but don't know how to do that.

Would love some help

Answer (score 15):

```
find /u1/database/prod/arch -type f -mtime +10 | wc -l
```

works here.

Comment: Can't get working on OS X (10.10.5) `wc: ;: open: No such file or directory
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`  I changed the first path `/u1/database/prod/arch` to an existing directory on my root drive. Otherwise used same exactly. I don't know `wc` but seems to count the lines printed by find command am I right?

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil pls check the tag on the question: `linux`

Comment: yeah I knew that, but linux and macOS have plenty of overlap at terminal level. this was closest existing question I could find to my problem

Answer (score 7):

You dont need the exec. use -print (or nothing) and find will print a line per file (and handle the recursion)

```
 find /u1/database/prod/arch -type f -mtime +10 -print | wc -l
```